# Ubuntu boot works with CD/DVD but not with USB

Tags: boot, usb, dvd

I decided to move from Windows to Ubuntu (I'm done playing World of Warcraft). The ISO I downloaded from Ubuntu webpage is working when I burn it to DVD and boot it whit my DVD ROM, but it doesn't work when I make live USB with Universal USB or Unetbootin. I try several USB sticks. It only shows blinking cursor and does nothing. In the past I was able to boot all versions of Windows trough USB (Xp, Vista, 7, 8) but I don't know why I cant boot Ubuntu with USB. I would install it via DVD it boots perfectly but it installs extremly slow because my DVD ROM is some kind of broken. On my desktop PC same happends, but it has a new DVD ROM and it installs Ubuntu fast, but same happends when I try to install it via USB.

My Laptop: Intel Core to Duo 2000, 4gbram, radeon hd3650m.
My Desktop: Amd Phenom x3 2200, 2GBram, Nvidia Gf9600gt.

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you give us some details about your machine?

Comment: Which windows are you using? What is the file system format of your Flash(Fat32, NTFS,...)? and did you make the USB flash drive as a first boot from boot order device in your BIOS settings?

Comment: Both PCs have Windows 7 Ultimate, Hard Disks are formated at NTFS, but usb stricks are FAT32 (I use quick format to fat32 before I make live USB)

Comment: Did you download the correct iso? (i.e., 32-bit or 64-bit)

Comment: Also, I've noticed [you already asked the same question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/526361/ubuntu-live-usb-shows-blinking-cursor-on-boot). Is the answer provided there \ the duplicate answer not helpful?

Comment: I downloaded it from Ubuntu webpage, the x64 one. I allready told it works with CD/DVD, I installed it on Desktop.

Comment: @Yuvi in that period I didn't tryed to install via CD/DVD, and now I updated this information in this topic.

Comment: There's no reason why the DVD would work while the USB wouldn't. The most reasonable explanation is that (a) there's something wrong with your usb or (b) there's something wrong with your port or (c) you're not actually booting from it correctly. I really can't think of any reason why else it would behave like that

Comment: you didn't tell me if you changed boot order device from BIOS or not :)

Comment: next time, update the original answer (closed questions are re-opened if they are edited and are no longer duplicates). also, option (d) - listen to @KasiyA

Comment: The USB sticks I used are many times formatted to NTFS for watching movies on my TV (10GB+ files). Can this be reason, should i format it once with fat32 (no quick format) ?

Comment: KasiyA and Yuvi, I tryed both F12 quick boot and Bios boot order, same happends, blinking screen and laptop fan starting to rotatee fast (seems like procesor is doing something)

Comment: No problem. your USB stick have had as FAT32 format and again [IS your USB device as first boot?](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/bootsequ.htm)

Comment: OK when cursor is blinking press arrow key (direction key) and check if anything happens

Comment: Currently it's not set as first boot device, I use F12 for quick Boot, and select USB.

Comment: press any key while cursor is blinking. have you any changes??

Comment: pressing arrow keys does nothing, pressing other keys causes beep

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be some BIOS settings issue, make sure you enable `legacy usb boot` in BIOS. Also enable `UEFI boot mode`.

I guess the boot order is set to usb first, or you keep pressing F12 / F8 on bootup to choose the usb device to boot from.

Comment: legacy usb boot is enabled, UEFI boot mode I don't see anywhere in my BIOS. I don't think its BIOS setting issue cos I can boot any version of windows at any time.